# Is a class of $n< \infty$ infinite sets a finite class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question**

Is a class of $n< \infty$ infinite sets a finite class?

**My Thought**

Suppose we have a class $S=\{N_1,N_2,...N_n\}$ where $N$ is a set with infinite members and $n<\infty$

Since $N_i \in S$, $i=\{1,2,...,n\}$ is itself a member of $S$, not its components. By definition, a class is finite if it has a finite $n$ members. Therefore, $S$ is a finite class.

**What I was Wondering**

Is my reasoning correct?

If not, what is the proper way to look at this?

Comment: You are correct: $S$ is a finite set, with precisely $n$ members (assuming that the sets $N_1,\dots,N_n$ are distinct sets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

The correct way is to verify that the definition of "finite" holds for $S$. The slightly more "mathematical" definition of finite would be:

> $S$ is finite if and only if there exists a bijection $f$ from $S$ onto a set of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, where $n\in\Bbb N$.

We can assume that $N_i\neq N_j$, then the function $f(N_i)=i-1$ is a bijection, as wanted.